# Random Doubled Results in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I run this query in MS Access:

```
SELECT q2.questionText, Answers.answerText
FROM Questions q2 INNER JOIN Answers ON q2.questionID = Answers.questionID
WHERE q2.questionID IN (SELECT TOP 15 q.questionID
FROM Questions q
ORDER BY RND(q.questionID));
```

I sometimes get doubled-up answerText rows. If I make a list of number from the output of this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 a.questionID
FROM Questions a
ORDER BY RND(a.questionID)
```

And use the numbers in the super query above:

```
SELECT q2.questionText, Answers.answerText
FROM Questions q2 INNER JOIN Answers ON q2.questionID = Answers.questionID
WHERE q2.questionID IN (125, 7, 44, 119, 85, 189, 159, 167, 11, 50, 23, 96, 18, 99, 121);
```

it works as expected. I'm enforcing referential integrity on the two questionID fields. I have been repeatedly deleting the tables and importing them again from a text file export that I added rows to. How to fix?

Comment: Are you certain you don't have multiple answers for the same questionID ?

Comment: Sometimes, instead of both "Yes" and "No" rows, I'll just get "No". Sometimes I'll get 1 1/2 of all possible answers to the question.

Comment: Is it the case that you always get 15 rows? i.e. the TOP 15 is being applied to the entire result set and not the subquery. Access is not perfect at complex queries, although the problems I've had have been with a much deeper nest.

Comment: I get 30-40 questions! Isn't there a better way to get random rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "repeatedly deleting the tables and importing them again from a text file export" thing caused duplications in the answers, which messed up the results. Removing the duplicates in the Answers table fixed the problem. Sorry for wasting your valuable time; I just didn't think of checking that until now.

Comment: This is what grahamj42 meant when he said "Are you certain you don't have multiple answers for the same questionID?" I now realize.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the RND(a.QuestionID) could give the same number on more than one occasion.  I would also suggest that "I sometimes get doubled-up answerText" means it works some of the time, and the second query has just worked by chance.

Perhaps something:

SELECT TOP 15 questionID FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 30 a.questionID
FROM Questions a
)
ORDER BY RND(questionID)

Might help, but it still will not guarantee that you get multiples of the same questionid, just it has a very much reduced chance and thus you should be able to get at least 15 questions out of the distinctly random generated set.

Comment: This gets two "Yes" rows instead of a "Yes" and "No" row:

    SELECT DISTINCT b.questionText, Answers.answerText, b.questionID, Answers.answerID
    FROM Questions AS b INNER JOIN Answers ON b.questionID = Answers.questionID
    WHERE Answers.questionID IN (
    SELECT TOP 15 a.questionID
    FROM Questions a
    ORDER BY RND(a.questionID)
    )
    ORDER BY b.questionID, Answers.answerID;

Random insanity.